# Trouble connecting NestJS app to MySQL database in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs

**Question:**

I am currently working on a NestJS application that needs to connect to a MySQL database, and I'm using Docker for containerization. However, I'm facing issues with the database connection. I've provided the relevant code and configuration below.

**Problem:**

The NestJS application is not able to connect to the MySQL database when running in a Docker container.
I have created a docker-compose.yml file and separate Dockerfiles for the NestJS backend and the MySQL database.

**Docker Compose File (docker-compose.yml):**

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./demo-tracker-frontend
    command: ["npm", "start"]
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - network

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./demo-tracker-backend
    command:
      ["sh", "-c", "npx prisma migrate deploy && npm run start:migrate:prod"]
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./demo-tracker-backend:/app_backend
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "mysql://root:#password@demo-tracker-mysql:3306/demo_tracker_mysql?connect_timeout=300"
    networks:
      - network

  mysql:
    build:
      context: ./mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: #password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: demo_tracker_mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 20
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - network

networks:
  network:
```

**Dockerfile for MySQL**

```dockerfile
FROM mysql:latest

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=30s \
  CMD mysqladmin ping -h localhost

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=passbackendtrackerword
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=demo_tracker_mysql

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["mysqld"]
```

**Dockerfile for NestJS backend**

```dockerfile
FROM node:18.17.1

WORKDIR /app_backend

COPY ./package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/

RUN npm install
RUN npx prisma generate
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:migrate:prod"]
```

**Issue:**

When I run docker-compose up, the NestJS backend container is unable to connect to the MySQL database container. I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: P1001: Can't reach the database server at `demo-tracker-mysql`:`3306`
```

**Additional Information:**

I've tried using the depends_on and networks options in my docker-compose.yml file to ensure that the backend service starts after the MySQL service and that they are on the same network.

I've verified that the MySQL container is healthy using docker ps, and it seems to be running without issues.

I've double-checked my database URL in the NestJS configuration, and it appears to be correctly set.

I'm also able to successfully connect to database container from outside of the container (using MySQL Workbench)

**Question:**
Can someone please help me identify what could be causing this issue? Is there a specific configuration or step that I might be missing when trying to connect my NestJS backend to the MySQL database in Docker?

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are setting the mysql host to "demo-tracker-mysql", which is not configured anywhere in docker-compose, try setting the host value to "mysql" in backend or try setting "container_name" in mysql service to "demo-tracker-mysql".

Change the "DATABASE_URL" environment variable in backend service to "mysql://root:#password@mysql:3306/demo_tracker_mysql?connect_timeout=300"

Comment: (I wouldn't bother setting `container_name:`.  I also might delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the file in the name of simplicity, using the `default` network Compose provides for you.)

Comment: @ArslanSohailBano I've actually tried setting 'mysql' but that didn't work either, the 'demo-tracker-mysql' is the containers name when i look it up

Comment: @DavidMaze The ```networks:```  weren't set the first time, I mean, they didn't really make any difference in my case.